# Same random number and string for each thread

Tags: jmeter

I need to generate the same JSON data twice for each thread for an HTTP request. I am having problem setting that up in JMeter. 
My structure is:

```
Test Plan
   - HTTP Header Manager
   - Thread Group 1 users, 5 loop
   - Random Variable, 
   - HTTP Request
```

I tried the combination of Per Thread User set to true and using seed for random function, but I can't achieve what I want. It keep on generating new number/string per loop.

Basically for each user, I want the exact same JSON request data.

Comment: why dont you use CSV config data?

Answer (score 0):

I see three decisions for your case:

- Use [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) before HTTP Request. Specify variables here. In this case it will be better to use [__Random() function](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/64307-using-jmeter-functions-part-ii) instead Random Variable.

> ```
> Test Plan
>    - HTTP Header Manager
>    - Thread Group 1 users, 5 loop
>    - User Defined Variables, (Name:varName; Value:${__Random(1,100)})
>    - HTTP Request
> ```

- Use [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) (loop count=5) before HTTP Request (instead loop=5 in Thread Group)

Comment: your solution works for numeric variable. But it doesn't work for string variables. I called RandomString function within HTTP Request, but the function keep changing value. The Http Request is inside the loop controller.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest another solution which seems to me verbose and awkward but no other idea.

You create file using BSF (or BeanShell) PreProcessor and write value of random variable into file. Then read file before every request. In the next example I used Groovy and BSF PreProcessor.

```
import java.util.Random  

def out= new File('File1.txt') // create file if it is not exists 
if(!out.exists()) 
{
  out.createNewFile()
  Random rand = new Random()  
  int max = 10  
  def a = rand.nextInt(max+1)  
  out << a // write text to file 
} 
//then read value of generated variable 
String fileContents = new File('File1.txt').text
//then put your variable into User defined Variable that I named HELLO 
vars.putObject("HELLO",fileContents)
```

And in needed request use ${HELLO}